# Select Statement result with space and without space

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Is there a way in MYSQL to search for all the records with spaces and without spaces and also by flipping the strings

Example:

```
Search String: JM Edward
```

Expected Result:

```
J M Edward
JM Edward
J MEdward
Edward J M
Edward JM
```

Comment: Sorry for the SQl Server tag, I'm using MYSQL here

Comment: This is not easily possible, even with regular expressions.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff how about Full-text searching using Match-Against?

Comment: Are you saying you want to be given a search string which consists of words separated optionally by spaces, and that the result should match any permutation of those words with those spaces optionally inserted? That's fairly complex for considering a single search. The full text search for "JM Edward" would find "JM Edward" or "Edward JM" or "JM ...(other stuff) ... Edward". But it won't find "J M Edward". You might need to pre-process the search string and generate a collection of one or more optional search strings/regexes to search for.

Comment: @min2bro . . . No.  First you are using single letters (which you can get around).  More importantly, you are combining them into a single word in some cases.  Your best bet may be something like Levenshtein distance.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for what your search? It would return all of the results.

```
SELECT * FROM Names
WHERE Names LIKE '%J%' and Names LIKE '%M%' and Names LIKE '%Edward%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, so your sql statement would look something similar to these

`Select * from table like %J%` 
Which will show all results with the letter J in it and for space you would do it like so:
`Select * from table % %`
Add a space in between

Comment: Just modified the search string. it's JM Edwards. How will it work in such cases? Look at my expected result also.

Comment: Those are going to match way more than what the OP wants to match.

Comment: So you add `Select * from table LIKE %JM Edwards%` if i understand you correctly

Comment: this will not return result J M Edward